# Does AX+XA=0 have any non-trivial solutions?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a continuous linear self-adjoint operator on some Hilbert space $H$ and for arbitrary compact operators $A$ we have: $XA+AX=0.$ Does this imply that $X=0$ or can there be non-trivial solutions to this equation?

Comment: Take $A,B$ to be a projections on orthogonal one-dimensional subspaces. $BXA+BAX=0$ and since $BA=0$ we get that $v\bot u\Rightarrow Xv\bot u$ and so $X$ has to be a constant times identity, from which it is $0$.

Comment: @FolkmarBornemann$X$ is self-adjoint and $A$ is an arbitrary compact operator.